# How to solve the leading zero error(syntax error) in evaluating a statement

Tags: python

Solve="30+05"
Print(eval(Solve))

#This shows leading zero error
#i want the Solve variable to be like Solve="30+5"

Comment: Don't write the leading zero in the first place? I don't see the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
solve="30+05" 
stripped_solve = "+".join([num.lstrip("0") for num in solve.split("+")])
print(eval(stripped_solve))
```